# how to execute command in java having whitespaces in pathname

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to take backup of database. I am using mysql databse and wamp server.For that i have written the following code.

```
Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.20\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -pkarma dailyreport -r  "+assign+"\\dailyreport.sql");  
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();  
if(processComplete == 0)
{  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup has been taken successfully", "BackUp", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} 
else 
{  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not take backup", "BackUp", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
}
```

In above code String assign denotes the the path where i want to save the backup of database. But problem is that i am taking the location to save backup at runtime.and if I select path where folder name contains space it could not take backup because System does not getting the path as it contains space.Please help me how should i change the runtime.getruntime.exec() command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the path in double quotes. That would help the shell see the entire argument as a single one instead of multiple arguments due to presence of space.

```
Process runtimeProcess = 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.20\\bin\\mysqldump.exe "
        + "-u root -pkarma dailyreport -r  \"" 
        + assign + "\\dailyreport.sql\" ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass the commands in as separate elements in a `String` array

```
String[] cmds = new String[] {
    "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.20\\bin\\mysqldump.exe",
    "-u",
    "root",
    "-pkarma",
    "dailyreport",
    "-r",
    assign+"\\dailyreport.sql"};

    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Each element in the array becomes a separate parameter for the command.

Better still, use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: @Vikdor oh how I know that feeling :P

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the `assign` String between quotes:

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql"
    + "\\mysql5.5.20\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -pkarma dailyreport "
    + "-r  \""+assign+"\"\\dailyreport.sql");
```